# Running Bamboo Ant Task on Linux CentOs

Tags: java, linux, ant, centos, bamboo

We have been trying to successfully configure a ANT task within our bamboo build on a local agent, Linux CentOs 6.5.

We consistently are getting the following error:

```
Could not find test result reports in the /var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/3080193/DIS-CF2016-JOB1 directory.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.  Program will exit.
```

Ant version is 1.7.1.  It is installed at /usr/bin/ant .  The lib directory for ant is located at /usr/share/ant/lib.

We have set the following environment variables for the bamboo user on the CentOs server

ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java

The java version is 1.6.  Ant builds work fine from the command line on the server.  Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this ended up being a matter of the environment settings not being picked up by the bamboo server.  Once the server was actually restarted by our IT group the ant task started working appropriately for us within bamboo builds.

AS indicated in the original question the two environment settings we added to the users profile were:

```
ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
```